# Why is the order not sorted properly while printing using the loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
student_name = {"Karrie", "Freya", "Bruno"}

for name in student_name:
print("The student name is {0}".format(name))
```

I am trying to run this loop but the order the result is in this form

```
The student name is Freya
The student name is Karrie
The student name is Bruno
```

Comment: **set** is unordered like **dictionary**. Use **list** / **tuple** based on requirements..

Answer (score 0):

Sets are unordered. If you're looking for an ordered collection, use a list:

```
student_name = ["Karrie", "Freya", "Bruno"]

for name in student_name:
    print("The student name is {0}".format(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sorted:

```
student_name = {"Karrie", "Freya", "Bruno"}
for name in sorted(student_name):
    print("The student name is {0}".format(name))
```